# How can I deal with Unity job system input and output?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to create a script that randomly places objects such as trees, rocks, and bushes throughout my terrain (I'm using Sebastian Lague's procedural generated terrain in case your wondering.) It became quite performance intensive so I decided to try out Unity's job system. I followed a few basic tutorials and learned quite a bit, but I just can't figure out how to pass in input to the job, and then receive output. Unity keeps telling me that I can't have multiple threads change the values of the NativeArray I am sending the job. I don't really know how I would attempt to create a different NativeArray for each separate job, complete all the jobs, and then use the output from each job to complete the instantiation of the objects in the main thread.

Here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Burst;

public class SpawnWorldObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WorldObject[] worldObjects;

    NativeArray<bool> isTouchingOtherObject = new NativeArray<bool>(1, Allocator.TempJob);
    NativeArray<Vector3> position = new NativeArray<Vector3>(1, Allocator.TempJob);
    NativeArray<RaycastHit> hit = new NativeArray<RaycastHit>(1, Allocator.TempJob);

    public void SpawnObjectsInChunk(Transform chunk, Vector2 sampleCenter, MeshSettings meshSettings, HeightMapSettings heightMapSettings)
    {
        NativeList<JobHandle> jobHandleList = new NativeList<JobHandle>(Allocator.Temp);

        for (int i = 0; i < worldObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < worldObjects[i].numberOfObjectsPerChunk; j++)
            {
                HeightMap heightMap = HeightMapGenerator.GenerateHeightMap(meshSettings.numVertsPerLine, meshSettings.numVertsPerLine, heightMapSettings, meshSettings, sampleCenter);

                CalculatePosition job = new CalculatePosition
                {
                    sampleCenter = sampleCenter,

                    meshWorldSize = meshSettings.meshWorldSize,
                    meshScale = meshSettings.meshScale,
                    numVertsPerLine = meshSettings.numVertsPerLine,

                    minValue = heightMap.minValue,
                    maxValue = heightMap.maxValue,

                    worldObjectMinSpawnHeight = worldObjects[i].minSpawnHeight,
                    worldObjectMaxSpawnHeight = worldObjects[i].maxSpawnHeight,
                    worldObjectDistanceFromOtherObjects = worldObjects[i].distanceFromOtherObjects,

                    isTouchingOtherObject = isTouchingOtherObject,
                    position = position,
                    hit = hit,
                };

                jobHandleList.Add(job.Schedule());
            }
        }

        JobHandle.CompleteAll(jobHandleList);

        for (int i = 0; i < worldObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < worldObjects[i].numberOfObjectsPerChunk; j++)
            {
                if (!isTouchingOtherObject[0])
                {
                    int typeOfObject = Random.Range(0, worldObjects[i].objectsToSpawn.Length - 1);

                    GameObject worldObject = Instantiate(worldObjects[i].objectsToSpawn[typeOfObject], new Vector3(position[0].x, hit[0].point.y, position[0].z), worldObjects[i].objectsToSpawn[typeOfObject].transform.rotation);
                    worldObject.transform.SetParent(chunk);
                }
            }
        }

        jobHandleList.Dispose();
        isTouchingOtherObject.Dispose();
        position.Dispose();
        hit.Dispose();
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class WorldObject
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToSpawn;
    public float distanceFromOtherObjects;
    public int numberOfObjectsPerChunk;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float minSpawnHeight;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float maxSpawnHeight;
}


public struct CalculatePosition : IJob
{
    public Vector2 sampleCenter;

    public float meshWorldSize;
    public float meshScale;
    public int numVertsPerLine;

    public float minValue;
    public float maxValue;

    public float worldObjectMinSpawnHeight;
    public float worldObjectMaxSpawnHeight;
    public float worldObjectDistanceFromOtherObjects;

    public NativeArray<bool> isTouchingOtherObject;
    public NativeArray<Vector3> position;
    public NativeArray<RaycastHit> hit;

    public void Execute()
    {
        float minSpawnHeight = Mathf.Lerp(minValue, maxValue, worldObjectMinSpawnHeight);
        float maxSpawnHeight = Mathf.Lerp(maxValue, maxValue, worldObjectMaxSpawnHeight);

        position[0] = new Vector3(Random.Range(sampleCenter.x - (float)meshWorldSize / 2, sampleCenter.x + (float)meshWorldSize / 2), 1000, Random.Range(sampleCenter.y - (float)meshWorldSize / 2, sampleCenter.y + (float)meshWorldSize / 2));

        RaycastHit _hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(position[0], Vector3.down, out _hit, 10000, 1 << 7))
        {
            hit[0] = _hit;

            if (_hit.point.y > minSpawnHeight && _hit.point.y < maxSpawnHeight)
            {
                RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.SphereCastAll(position[0], worldObjectDistanceFromOtherObjects, Vector3.down);

                isTouchingOtherObject[0] = false;

                foreach (RaycastHit __hit in hits)
                {
                    if (__hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 9)
                    {
                        isTouchingOtherObject[0] = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to make a list of every thing you want to do and use parallel jobs. Code Monkey on YouTube has some good content explaining this.